# Прослушивание событий клавиатуры вне приложения Java

Tags: java, события, listener, keypress

Пытаюсь создать приложение, которое при нажатии на определенную клавишу клавиатуры, будет автоматически нажимать другие комбинации клавиш, например: 
при нажатии на клавишу R - будет срабатывать комбинация Right Shift + S 
В процессе написания столкнуля с рядом проблем:
1) как сделать так, что бы программа мониторила нажатие клавиш при неактивном окне приложения?
2) как вызвать автоматическое нажатие правого шифта, или другой клавиши, имеющей 2 физических ключа на клавиатуре (важно нажать именно конкретную клавишу).

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Мой код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    static Robot robot;

    {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MyFrame(String Cap) {

        super(Cap);

        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setVisible(true);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

                switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_R:
                        feintOne();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void feintOne() {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame("Don't mention it");

    }
}
```

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает (хотя могу ошибаться), вы выбрали неверный язык. Приложения java работают на виртуальной машине JVM и не имеют нормального доступа к тому, что творится за пределами окна приложения. Плюс к этому такие функции ОС зависимы, значит нужна некая оболочка для кросплатформенной джавы. Например под windows мог бы быть задействован api https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey Если придумаете как это вызывать из java, то тогда надежда есть ...

Comment: Возможно подскажете, как реализовать это на C++?

Comment: Слушать клаву видимо тем что указал выше, посылать события https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318559/how-to-send-keyboard-events-to-all-kind-of-applications-in-windows